# How to add two or more kotlin native modules on an iOS project

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

## TL;DR;

How to add two or more kotlin native modules on an iOS project without getting `duplicate symbols` error?

## The detailed question

Let's assume a multi-module KMP project as a follow where there exists a native app for Android and a native app for iOS and two common modules to hold shared kotlin code.

```sh
.
├── android
│   └── app
├── common
│   ├── moduleA
│   └── moduleB
├── ios
│   └── app
```

The module A contains a data class HelloWorld and has no module dependencies:

```kotlin
package hello.world.modulea

data class HelloWorld(
    val message: String
)
```

Module B contains an extension function for HelloWorld class so it depends on module A:

```kotlin
package hello.world.moduleb

import hello.world.modulea.HelloWorld

fun HelloWorld.egassem() = message.reversed()
```

The build.gradle configuration of the modules are:

- Module A

```
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods"

…

kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm("android")

        def iosClosure = {
            binaries {
                framework("moduleA")
            }
        }
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos")) {…}
    }

    cocoapods {…}

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.72"
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
        }
        iosMain.dependencies {
        }
    }
}
```

- Module B

```
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.cocoapods"
…

kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm("android")

        def iosClosure = {
            binaries {
                framework("moduleB")
            }
        }
        if (System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos")) {…}
    }

    cocoapods {…}

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.72"
            implementation project(":common:moduleA")
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
        }
        iosMain.dependencies {
        }
    }
}
```

It looks pretty straightforward and it even works on android if I configure the android build gradle dependencies as a following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72"
    implementation project(":common:moduleA")
    implementation project(":common:moduleB")
}
```

However, this does not seem to be the correct way to organize multi modules on iOS, because running the `./gradlew podspec` I get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` as expected with the following pods:

```rb
pod 'moduleA', :path => '…/HelloWorld/common/moduleA'
pod 'moduleB', :path => '…/HelloWorld/common/moduleB'
```

Even running a `pod install` I get a success output `Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.` whats looks correctly once the Xcode shows the module A and module B on the Pods section.

However, if I try to build the iOS project I get the following error:

```sh
Ld …/Hello_World-…/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hello\ World.app/Hello\ World normal x86_64 (in target 'Hello World' from project 'Hello World')
    cd …/HelloWorld/ios/app
…
duplicate symbol '_ktypew:kotlin.Any' in:
    …/HelloWorld/common/moduleA/build/cocoapods/framework/moduleA.framework/moduleA(result.o)
    …/HelloWorld/common/moduleB/build/cocoapods/framework/moduleB.framework/moduleB(result.o)
… a lot of duplicate symbol more …
duplicate symbol '_kfun:kotlin.throwOnFailure$stdlib@kotlin.Result<#STAR>.()' in:
    …/HelloWorld/common/moduleA/build/cocoapods/framework/moduleA.framework/moduleA(result.o)
    …/HelloWorld/common/moduleB/build/cocoapods/framework/moduleB.framework/moduleB(result.o)
ld: 9928 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My knowledge in iOS is not that much, so to my untrained eyes, it looks like each module is adding its own version of the things instead of using some resolutions strategy to share it.

If I use only the module A the code works and run as expected, so I know the code itself is correct, the problem is how to manage more than 1 module, so that the question, how to add both (module A and module B) on iOS and make things works?

## P.S

I did reduce the code as much as I could, trying to keep only the parts that I guess is the source of the problem, however, the complete code is available [here](https://github.com/ademar111190/kmp-multimodules-doubt) if you want to check anything missing in the snippets, or if you want to run and try to solve the problem…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple Kotlin frameworks can be tricky, but should be working as of 1.3.70 which I see you have.

The issue seems to be that both frameworks are static, which is currently an issue in 1.3.70 so it isn't working. (This should be updated by 1.40). It looks like by default the cocoapods plugin sets the frameworks to be static which won't work. I'm unaware of a way to change cocoapods to set it as dynamic but I've tested building without cocoapods and using the `isStatic` variable in a gradle task, and have gotten an iOS project to compile. Something like:

```
binaries {
    framework("moduleA"){
        isStatic = false
    }
}
```

For now you can work around the issue using this method by using the code above and creating a task to build the frameworks([here's an example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#building-universal-frameworks))

Another thing worth noting is that on the iOS side, the HelloWorld classes will appear as two separate classes despite both coming from moduleA. It's another strange situation with multiple Kotlin frameworks, but I think the extension will still work in this case since you're returning a string.

I actually just wrote up a blog post about multiple Kotlin frameworks that may help with some other questions if you'd like to take a look. https://touchlab.co/multiple-kotlin-frameworks-in-application/

**EDIT**: Looks like `cocoapodsext` also has an `isStatic` variable, so set it to `isStatic = false`

tl:dr You currently can't have more than one static Kotlin frameworks in the same iOS project. Set them to not be static using `isStatic = false`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer and the complementary material is what I was looking for.
The problems you raise are relevant, with that in mind I'm following this strategy:
Keep the modularization (target of the question)
For Android, I kept normal gradle modules
For native modules, I'd add a "fat" module with no code and a gradle configuration to use all other modules code together and generates a single framework solving the class prefix problem and the duplicated symbols as well.

Comment: Hopefully, future versions of kotlin get better multi-module support for native, so I can get rid of the fat module and use the already organized modules. for now lets work with that :D

Comment: @ademar111190 what exactly is wrong with the "fat" module approach in your case?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As an Android dev who is starting with iOS, I bumped into the same issue. With the static/dynamic solution, you have to decide if you can live with the namespace problem as the article suggests. I personally didn't like having a module's name as a prefix so I ended up keeping the modules as they are for android but making one of them export the dependencies of the second one transitively. 
```framework { baseName = "moduleA" export("moduleB") transitiveExport = true }```

Comment: Using, Kotlin 1.7.20 and almost nothing has changed, we are still getting 2 Swift classes generated for a single Kotlin class.

Comment: @MichaelBakogiannis Can you elaborate, please? Even with your implementation, Kotlin class is interpreted as two different Swift classes in different frameworks. Have you really tested your implementation or it was just theory?

Answer (score 2):

> However, if I try to build the iOS project I get the following error:

This particular error is a known issue. Multiple debug static frameworks are incompatible with compiler caches.

So to workaround the issue you can either disable compiler caches by putting the following line into your `gradle.properties`:

```
kotlin.native.cacheKind=none
```

or make the frameworks dynamic by adding the following snippet to your Gradle build script:

```kotlin
kotlin {
    targets.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget> {
        binaries.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.Framework> {
            isStatic = false
        }
    }
}
```

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42254 for more details.

I guess current behaviour for multiple frameworks doesn't make much sense for the original topic starter, I'm just putting my answer here for anyone who might encounter the same issue.

> My knowledge in iOS is not that much, so to my untrained eyes, it looks like each module is adding its own version of the things instead of using some resolutions strategy to share it.

This is exactly how it is supposed to work at this moment. But "versions of the things" in each of the frameworks are put into the separate independent namespaces, so there should be no linkage errors, and the one you've encountered is a bug.