# Importing KMM library in multiple iOS modules via Cocoapods results in "... implemented in both ..."

Tags: cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I have been maintaining a shared library built with Kotlin Multiplatform for our Android and iOS native apps for quite some time now. Was working great until I decided to split the iOS app into multiple modules (frameworks). For starters I have one iOS app project and two dynamic frameworks, which are used by the app project. All 3 projects are using Cocoapods for 3rd party dependency management. Own modules are imported via framework embedding. No Cocoapods for the own modules needed, because we don't plan to make them available to other projects.

So the issue I am facing now is that whenever I import the KMM framework into more than one of the modules via Cocoapods, the build succeeds, but I receive errors at runtime like

> Class MyClassInKMMProject is implemented in both
> /Users/{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hcbcxlfmsfiiqaccahedgcclxmiq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Common.framework/Common
> (0x1189318d0) and
> /Users/{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-hcbcxlfmsfiiqaccahedgcclxmiq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Core.framework/Core
> (0x112a77ea8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Since I need the shared KMM library basically in every module, I am stuck right now with this issue.

In some community I remember that someone mentioned static libraries can be imported only once when using multiple modules. But as far as I understand KMM generated frameworks and not static libraries.

I also tried using XCFrameworks instead of Frameworks, but it didn't change anything.

Anyone here knows how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to find a solution for several days, but just found it after writing this question.

Adding `isStatic=false` to Gradle was the solution, which I got from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420364/390542